# What is the correct and more-native position of the word 'are' in the following sentences?

Tags: word-order, reported-speech

What is the correct and more-native  position of the word 'are' in the following sentences?

*someone asked me what are my plans for halloween

*someone asked me what my plans for halloween are

Comment: Please do some research on reported speech before asking this question.

Comment: Neither of these sentences would normally be considered correct in reported speech. If somebody *asked*, then the past tense would normally be used in this case: *Somebody asked me what my plans for Halloween* ***were***.

Comment: Backshifted "were" is certainly possible, but present tense "are" is fine too.

Comment: @Jason Bassford If someone asked you in the past on Oct 29 about your plans in the future, Oct 31, then you can use "are".

Comment: @HiddenBabel You *can* but only if the time hasn't already passed. Halloween was two days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We either say

> Someone asked me what my plans for Halloween are.

or

> Someone asked me what my plans are for Halloween.

But we never use your first sentence. That word order is for asking a question,

> Someone asked me, "What are your plans for Halloween?"

Answer (score 0):

> [1] * *Someone asked me [what are my plans for Halloween]*.
>
> [2] *Someone asked me [what my plans for Halloween are].*

The position of “are” has an important effect on the grammaticality.

The bracketed elements are subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded question). Such clauses do not normally have subject-auxiliary inversion, and hence [2] is fine but [1], which does have inversion, is ungrammatical.

The meaning of [2] can be glossed as “Someone asked me the answer to the question ‘What are my plans for Halloween?’”